# How can I maintain probability across multiple executions in Java

Tags: java, math, random, probability

Firstly I am not the greatest with Math, so please excuse any ignorance relating to that. I am trying to maintain probability based randomness across multiple executions but I am failing. I have this input in a JSONObject

```
{
   "option1": 25,
   "option2":25,
   "option3" :10,
   "option4" :40
}
```

This is my function that selects a value from the above JSONObject based on the probability assigned:

```
public static String selectRandomoptions(JSONObject options) {
    String selectedOption = null;

    if (options != null) {

        int maxChance = 0;
        for (String option : options.keySet()) {
            maxChance += options.getInt(option);
        }

        if (maxChance < 100) {
            maxChance = 100;
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        Integer randomValue = r.nextInt(maxChance);

        int chance = 0;
        for (String option : options.keySet()) {
            chance += options.getInt(option);
            if (chance >= randomValue) {
                selectedOption = options.toLowerCase();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the function behaves within a reasonable error margin if I call it x amount of times in a single execution ( tested 100+ calls), the problem is that I am running this every hour to generates some sample data in an event-driven app to verify our analytics process/data but we need it to be somewhat predictable, at least within a reasonable margin?

Has anyone any idea how I might approach this? I would rather not have to persist anything but I am not opposed to it if it makes sense or reduces complexity/time.

Comment: What sort of thing are you looking for in terms of predictability? Do you always want the same sequence or with the same probabilities.

Comment: @Salixalba basically this function generates a request body that a generated unique user sends to our system, can be anywhere between 24 & 200 a day (divided into different sized hourly blocks) over multiple weeks. after a week or even daily, I would expect to see results of the number of different generated requests to closely match the probability assigned but there seems to be a very large varience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values returned by `Random.nextInt()` are uniformly distributed, so that shouldn't be a problem.

I you would like to make random results repeatable, then you may want to use [`Random` with seed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than create a new Random() object each time you want a new random number, just create the Random object once per run, and use the `Random.nextInt()` object once per run.

Looking at the documentation of `Random()` constructor,

> This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a
>   value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this
>   constructor.it only guarantees it to be different

that's a bit of a weaker contract than the number you get from `nextInt()`.

If you want to get the same sequence of numbers on each run, use the `Random(long seed)` or the `setSeed(long seed)` method of the random object. Both these methods set the seed of the generator. If you used the same seed for each invocation it's guaranteed that you will get the same sequence of numbers from the generator.
[Random.setSeed(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long)).

Comment: Do not create a new Random inside the method call.  It should be a class member.

Comment: @duffymo excuse my lack of understanding but can you explain why having it in a method call is bad/wrong?

Comment: Because the random number generator is a sequence generator that works off of past generated values.   A new object for every new value has no idea what other instances that have already been garbage collected have done.  Look at Knuth random number generation algorithm.